# Effect of function location on overall performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a rather large javascript application and am trying to optimize performance. If I have a loop that will execute a small function thousands of times, does putting the small function far away, code-wise, from the calling function have any performance implications? Thank You.

Comment: how far away? just wanna know...

Comment: If it's over 1000 lines away, it may be better to move the function closer to the function call. This, of course, is to support IE. Otherwise it has no effect on the function call in a standards-compliant browser.

Comment: Is your loop in the US and the function in Europe? because that's pretty far.

Comment: I'd guess approximately 300 lines away. Thanks

Comment: Would it be better to wrap the smaller function into an object with the calling function, vs having both in the global scope?

Comment: No function location does not matter in lines. However, if the function is far in terms of closure level. It may cause some performance issues. But, it is still negligible most of the time.

Comment: It is kind of useful, it is clear, but it seems to be a very theoretical concern...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference declaring the function in loop or calling it after each iteration. I have been taught that each function and variable according to its size creates its space in RAM at specified location. Javascript knows where that function or variable is located in memory because we assign it a name like `foo`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) foo(i);
... Your 300 lines
function foo(i) {
   document.body.innerHTML += i+"<br />";
}
```

or

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   document.body.innerHTML += i+"<br />";
}
```

You can use the way you like. The functions when declared have fixed position in memory thus can be called from anywhere. You can also call it from Europe if it is located there.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question and including the Europe comment ;)

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if the OP were in Europe... would the call be after or during work hours?

Comment: Ick, not to mention the Timezone issues.

Comment: @icedwater Ofcourse, during work hours. His job is to server until the server is on. These scripts force server shutdowns so, they can rest for some time.